# This is the given problem statement(attached in the image). It uses the concepts of lists and dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've attached the problem statement in the image.
I somehow managed to get the "similar" output in the form of a list because dictionary needs to have a "unique" key all the time.
Here's my code:

```
l=[]

words=[a for a in 'aaabccdd']
for i in words:
    l.append((i,words.count(i)))
h = list(set(l))   
print(h)
```

output of my code is:

```
[('a', 3), ('d', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
```

but I want it in the form of a dictionary like this :

```
{1:['b'], 2:['c', 'd'], 3:['a']}
```

where count(frequency) acts as a key to the dictionary and elements with common frequency comes in the form of a list as shown above.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5KLV.png)

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to put the output in that form.

Comment: Don't use an image, paste the problem statement as text.

Comment: Someone was nice enough to fix the code formatting for you, then you undid it with your edit. Please take a look at the edit history and fix it again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to go from

```
[('a', 3), ('d', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
```

to

```py
{1:['b'], 2:['c', 'd'], 3:['a']}
```

Here is the piece of code to achieve this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for word, count in h:
    d[count].append(word)

print(d)
```

---

Or the full program:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


l=[]

words=[a for a in 'aaabccdd']
for i in words:
    l.append((i,words.count(i)))
h = list(set(l))   


d = defaultdict(list)
for word, count in h:
    d[count].append(word)

print(d)
```

---

if you are not allowed to use `defaultdict`, you can use the following:

```py
l=[]

words=[a for a in 'aaabccdd']
for i in words:
    l.append((i,words.count(i)))
h = list(set(l))   


d = {}
for word, count in h:
    if count in d:
        d[count].append(word)
    else:
        d[count] = [word]
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
new_dict = {}
for  key,val in dict(Counter('aaabccdd')).items():
    if val not in new_dict:
        new_dict[val] = key
    elif type(new_dict[val]) == list:
        new_dict[val].append(key)
    else:
        new_dict[val] = [new_dict[val]]+[key]
print (new_dict)
```

output:

```
{3: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: ['c', 'd']}
```

Comment: I wouldn't put extra effort into encouraging their misrepresentation of the task...